# Facebook social buttons not working in jquery/rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I've been pulling my hair out trying to fix this issue.

if I go to: https://rbzexercise.herokuapp.com/workouts/4

the Facebook like button shows up, but if I click on another workout (i use ajax to get to another workout) the like button disappears. When I refresh the like button returns. I know it has something to do with my use of jquery, but I dont know how to fix it.

I'm using rails 3.2.1, ruby 1.9.2. I hope thats enough info, if not let me know.

Thanks for any help!

Update:
the facebook code is in script within a partial

```
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("div.dright").append('<div class="fb-like" data-href="<%= likepage_workout_url(workout) %>" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>')
     });
     </script>
```

its run via my show.js.erb file:

```
     $("div.descbar").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('workouts/title', :workout => @workout)) %>");
```

Comment: How are you initializing the Facebook like button? Are you re-initializing it after your ajax call has loaded the content?

Comment: how do you reinitialize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling FB.XFBML.parse on the HTMLElement object that contains the FB Like button. When you switch workouts, in your event handler, use the following at the end of the function:

```
FB.XFBML.parse($(".dright")[0]);
```

This means: grab the .dright container, and have the FB JS SDK parse its contents for any Like buttons (and any other markup-based FB social plugins).

NB: You cannot use this on the element itself, but the containing element: hence my grabbing your `.dright` container, and not each `.fb-like` element.

Comment: Btw, if you want to see this before you code it, open up your page and your JS console. Change workouts, then drop the above code into the console, and see the FB Like Button appear. (That's how I tested this.)

Comment: All I am getting is undefined in the console.

Comment: If you are getting an error from the console, change the "$" to "jQuery"